# Creating a chromakey animated-gif playing for streaming overlay

Tags: html, streaming, animated-gif

You know soundboards? Hit a button, play a sound? I don't see why that can't be developed for animated gifs.

All the parts are lying around, but I'm not a coder. Scratch that: I've been known to cobble together functional HTML together with the right Lynda training. I'm surely willing to learn what is needed, but *that's* where I must turn to you. Because I need one or two of you code-fu programmer-types to point me in the right direction.

Here is how I've been picturing it:

HTML **Page A** is just a collection of links. Each of those links opens in a named HTML **Page B**, which would be where all other links would send to as well. Page B would have a chromakey background color of your choosing. Each animated gif would need only be played once rather than looped.

A more feature-rich version of this is what [Streamlabs](https://streamlabs.com) already does - Twitch notifications.

What is killing me, and the reason why I haven't posted, like, a week ago, is because every time I sit down to post to these forums, I shake my head and say "there's no way this thing doesn't exist already" and go back to searching.

Anyway, any pointy-actions are much appreciated and thanks for taking the time to read this.